# Is this a standard color palette?

Tags: c#, colors, reverse-engineering

I am doing some reverse engineering work on a program. One of the things I am trying to pull out of the old data is a color that was chosen from the below color pallet

[image]

The way the old software is refrencing the color is by the index in the pallet (so 0 is white, 1 is yellow, 2 is orange, and so on). Is the above pallet a standard layout of some type?

What my best hope is to find some class built in to .NET where I could pass the same index number in and get the color back, however I don't have high hopes for finding something that nice.

Besides using paint and an eyedropper to manually map out the whole table is there any option to make this easier on me?

Comment: You could write some code that reads that bitmap and examines the pixels to build a palette.

Comment: Very good idea, `5 + (10 * (i % 16))`, `5 + (10 * (i / 16))` would give me the center of every square (after I cropped it to 160x160 px), post that as an answer and I would up-vote it (and would accept it too if nothing else came along)

Comment: It is not.  The stock Windows palette has 10 fixed colors in the beginning and 10 at the end.  There are of course a near infinite number of ways to group 256 colors.  Use the Image.Palette property.

Comment: it's too bad StackOverflow discourages trivial edits... this title... argh!

Comment: @redtuna Tell me what you think a better title would be and I would change it.

Comment: @Scott: "Is this a standard color palette?". A palette is a set of colors (historically, it's where a painter mixes their colors). A pallet is a thing you put boxes on, so you can forklift them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some code that reads that bitmap and examines the pixels to build the palette of colors in the bitmap you've extracted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 16 x 16 = 256 palette. The old Software possibly stored this palette in a [gif-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format). You could build an array of hex values from this palette (hard coded or at runtime).

The first row is a "useful"-colors row.

Row two to eight shifts hue values from hue 338° to hue 335°.

Row nine to fifteen show (7) tints and (8) shades (HSB color model) of hue 0°, 30°, 60°, 116°, 180°, 230° and 300°.

Last row is obviously a grayscale.

I don't think this is a standard layout. If you want an exact value, you need to use the eyedropper...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [SLaks suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467441/is-this-a-standard-color-pallet/16467945?noredirect=1#comment23626066_16467441) and just looped over the image and read the pixel values from the center of each square. Here is quick proof of concept test I ran that loaded all of the colors in to a `TableLayoutPanel` and it worked perfectly.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pngPath = @"E:\Color Pallet.png";
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pngPath))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            var color = bitmap.GetPixel(5 + (10*(i%16)), 5 + (10*(i/16)));
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Panel {Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = color}, i % 16, i / 16);
        } 
    }
```

@SLaks, if you post your own answer I will delete mine and accept yours.